# How to open a GUI application and 'disconnect' it?

Tags: command-line, gui

I can run Sublime, for example, in the background by typing

```
sublime-text &
```

The `&` puts it into the background so that I can continue to run commands in my terminal. Alternatively, I can run

```
sublime-text
```

Which locks up my terminal. If I then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> it "suspends" the application which essentially freezes it (it will eventually turn gray). Typing `bg` moves it into the background and unlocks the terminal.

In any case, if I exit the terminal or type `fg` and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the application will close.

How do I "disconnect" the GUI application from the terminal so that it will *not* close should I close the terminal or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>? In other words, I would like to use the terminal as a launcher, which is particularly convenient when I want to open a specific file: e.g., `sublime-text /path/to/my/file <super-secret-character-that-disconnects-the-app-not-just-puts-it-in-the-bg>`.

Comment: How about using XTERM instead of the Normal Terminal

Comment: @Tasos: You're going to have to elaborate on that. I've only got a vague idea of what xterm is, and I don't know how it solves this particular problem.

Comment: Its an alternative to a terminal. Its comes with Ubuntu and does the same stuff as a Normal terminal. Doesn't Sublime come with an Icon anyway you can start it that way or do you actually need the Terminal for some reason i didn't understand?

Comment: Could you please explain how/why is it more convenient to use `sublime-text /path/to/my/file <super-secret-character-that-disconnects-the-app-not-just-puts-it-in-the-bg>` from a terminal than double-clicking (or right-click, open with) the filename in a file manager?

Comment: @DKBose I too launch my editor mostly by command line; I can use tab completion, shell variables, gobbling for multiple files, `find` tricks... Infinitely faster than browsing the graphical file manager. For example `gvim -p convert*.[ch]`...

Comment: @Rmano, thanks for explaining. Seems quite complicated though!

Comment: @DKBose It's really not that complicated. In addition to that, I've got stuff on my `$PATH` that might not be available in ubuntu's search thing, and I really don't want to screw around with `.desktop` files and icons just to get it in there. I find it doesn't even work very well even when it's properly set up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `disown` command to detach background processes from the terminal.

If you have only one running background job, you can simply use

```
disown
```

and the owner of this background process will no longer be the terminal, so it will keep running even after the terminal is closed.

Comment: So, a more concise way might be: `sublime-text ~/.zshrc&; disown`

Comment: Yes. `sublime-text ~/.zshrc & disown`. This way it just works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Under bash, use the disown command to fix an existing process.  To get the list of background processes attached to the current shell, use the `jobs` command.  Then to disown the desired process, use `disown % <job number>`.  Below is an example of how to disown xload.

```
jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 man man
[2]-  Running                 xload &
[3]-  Running                 xeyes &

disown %2
```

To prevent the problem from the start, use the nohup command.  So I would add this line to your .bashrc file:

```
alias sublime-text='nohup sublime-text'
```

Then type `sublime-text < filename> &`.

Comment: This prints an annoying message, "nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’"

Answer (score 2):

`nohup gedit &`. Now you can just press enter to continue entering commands and stuff and if you close the terminal, gedit will stay open.