# How to run GUI program in remote shell via xterm and then close xterm without kill program

Tags: ssh, remote, xserver, xterm

I need to launch a program having a GUI, press "start" button on it and then close xterm keeping up the program till the end of his process. How do I do that?

Comment: `ssh -Y user@host.example.com /path/to/GUI-interface-binary & logout`

Comment: What is the program? Many (most?) programs have a command-line interface as well.

Comment: @DopeGhoti That accomplishes the first half (launching the program and clicking "start") but not the second half (closing xterm, keeping the program running until it's done)

Comment: See my amended suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a GUI application and 'disconnect' it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/439187/how-to-open-a-gui-application-and-disconnect-it)

Comment: @steeldriver it doesn't help me.